# What is the type of `return` or `del`?

Tags: python, syntax, naming

I don't think that they're functions, and I can't use `type(return)` to get an answer (it will raise an error).

What are they called? Could I define something similar?

Comment: [del](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-del_stmt) and [return](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement) ?

Comment: Yes, and like Martijn said, now I know that they called _statements_. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`return` and `del` are *statements*. They are not objects, so they don't have a type. Statements form the syntax of the language, objects form the datamodel the syntax operates on.

See the [*Simple Statements* reference page](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html) for their documentation. There are also [*Compound Statements*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html); statements that contain groups of more statements.

Because both `del` and `return` are statements, their names are also [reserved keywords](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords), which means you cannot use them to create identifiers. All words used in statements are keywords<sup>*</sup>, but not all keywords are (part of) statements.

You cannot define your own statements in Python itself, you'd have to extend the language implementation itself (so extend the Python grammar, tokenizer, parser, AST model and interpreter).

---

<sup>*</sup> with the current exception being the words [`async` and `await`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#coroutines) which are *temporarily* not keywords outside of coroutines to help transition existing code to Python 3.5; making them keywords now would potentially break too much existing code that doesn't yet use coroutines *anyway*. See the [PEP 492 transition plan](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#transition-plan); the plan is to make them keywords in [Python 3.7](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#deprecation-plans).

Comment: _statements_? Let me see the document :)

Comment: Well, what's the difference between _statements_ and _keywords_?

Comment: @KevinGuan: I already explained that; keywords are reserved names that cannot be used as identifiers (names of variables). They are reserved because otherwise the parser would not be able to distinguish between statements and identifiers (which are a part of expressions).

Comment: @KevinGuan Martijn knows everything about python, but that doesn't mean you should ask him everything. Your questions/requests here in the comments can easily be googled

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yes you're right, I'm sorry about that. Thanks Martijn, I understand now :). And I'll accept the answer in  4 minutes.